# Как работает этот фрагмент (?!word\b)?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

```
\b(?!word\b)\S{4,16}\b
```

Не понял, как работает это выражение в этом месте: `(?!word\b)\S`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это negative lookahead. В данном случае означает, что не может быть отдельно стоящего слова `word`.

- `\b` ― граница слова (`(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`)
- `(?!word\b)` ― отсутствие сочетания `word` + граница слова
- `\S{4,16}\b` ― непробельные 4-16 символов + граница слова

Например:

> `word` ― не найдёт
>
> `word hello` ― не найдёт `word`, но найдёт `hello`
>
> `word123456789ABC` ― найдёт
>
> `word123456789ABCD` ― не найдёт

Comment: Та за шо минус?

Comment: А что такое `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)` (где `\b`)?

Comment: @Scourde объяснение, что такое граница слова: буква в начале строки, конце, после/перед небуквы

Comment: А как понимать `?!` в этом выражении? Я не совсем понял

Comment: @Scourde `(?!...)` ― negative lookahead, т.е. содержимое этих скобок (`...`) не должно встречаться. В данном случае не должно встречаться `word\b`, именно поэтому первые 2 примера не находятся (потому что стоит `word$` в первом, `word\W` во втором)

Comment: Я так понял, что не будет искаться именно то слово, которое указано в скобочках, т.е. `word`. Я правильно понимаю? Тогда как сделать так, чтобы таким образом можно было бы не "искать" несколько слов? Например, `word` и `hass`?

Comment: @Scourde не просто `word`, а `word\b`. Для нескольких слов `(word|hass)\b`